# Checking if calculation will cause overflow c++

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

I added the elseif statement in collatz() to check if workingnumber * 3 + 1 will go over INT_MAX but when running the program some numbers which should not go over INT_MAX are reported as doing so. I might not need to cast INT_MAX but I'm not sure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

void collatz( int startingnumber ) {

    int count = 0;

    int originalnumber = startingnumber;

    int workingnumber = startingnumber;

    while( workingnumber >= 1 ) {

        if( workingnumber == 1 ) {

            cout << originalnumber << " takes " << count << " steps" << endl;

            count = 0;

            break;
        }

        if( workingnumber % 2 == 0 ) {

            workingnumber /= 2;

            //optional
            //cout << originalnumber << " is at " << workingnumber << endl;

            count++;
        }
        else if( ( ( long int ) workingnumber * 3 ) + 1 > ( long int ) INT_MAX ) {

            cout << originalnumber << " will cause a buffer overflow" << endl;

            break;
        }        
        else {

            workingnumber = ( 3 * workingnumber ) + 1;

            //optional
            //cout << originalnumber << " is at " << workingnumber << endl;

            count++;
        }
    }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {

    int increment = 2;

    if( argc > 1 ) {

        if( atoi( argv[1] ) != 0 ) {

            increment = atoi( argv[1] );
        }
    }

    while( increment <= INT_MAX ) {

        collatz( increment );

        increment++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean just "overflow" when you say "buffer overflow"? Buffer overflow is `int arr[10]; arr[11] = 42;`. Overflow is math that causes the number to exceed the limits. Also, your code relies on `long` being bigger than `int`.

Comment: workingnumber would stop at 2147483622 because going through the while loop it would exceed the maximum value for an int. I wanted to catch that before it happened and skip the number

Comment: So, overflow, not buffer-overflow, but "integer-overflow", or generally overflow.

Comment: `<= INT_MAX` is always true and once you overflow, you have undefined behaviour. You need to abort your loop after collatzing MAX_INT, but before incrementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [operetor precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) rules put the c-style cast (long int) at the same priority as `*` and with assiociativity from right to left. So first the multiplication is done and then the casting.

Try

```
else if( ( (( long int ) workingnumber) * 3 ) + 1 > INT_MAX )
```

*Attention also:  on some implementations, `long` may have the same precisions than `int`  (for example [MSVC2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)). You can easily check for your C++ compiler by using [`numeric_limits`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/).  You could opt for `long long int` if necessary.*

Comment: Or `workingnumber * (long) 3` or a constructor-style cast `long(workingnumber) * 3`

Comment: That seems to have worked, I didn't notice it before but numbers that would cause an overflow were skipped over

Comment: Better than using `long long int` (which isn't even safe since the standard allows it to have the same size as an `int`, though I don't know any platform where this is the case), a simpler test can be done. See my answer.

Comment: @vinc17  In practive in all the compilers I know, have either `long` or `long long` larger than `int` . But you are right: the standard doesn't give this garantee.  The drawback of your solution is that it can't be generalized if there are several variables.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to operate on large numbers, it's better that you use a arbitrary-precision arithmetics library, like [GNU MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org).

That way, you don't need to worry about integer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your test with `long int` will not work if a `long int` has the same size as an `int`. To check whether workingnumber * 3 + 1 fits in an `int` in a portable way (and in a faster way), you should test:

```
workingnumber <= (INT_MAX - 1) / 3
```

Note that the right term of the comparison is a constant, so that the test is very fast.

Comment: Good idea !  +1 !  At least in this case where there is only one variable.  Further improvement:  `abs(workingnumber) <= (INT_MAX - 1) / 3`  ;-)